# port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform while building the Alexa Auto SDK on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: build, alexa-skills-kit, gnulib, alexa-auto-sdk

Building Alexa Auto SDK https://github.com/alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/blob/3.2/builder/README.md

Using Ubuntu 20.04 (I've no more 18.04) I run with

```
./builder/build.sh android -t androidx86-64 --android-api 28
```

into

```
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c: In function ‘freadahead’:
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c:92:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|    92 |  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|       |   ^~~~~
| make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: freadahead.o] Error 1
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c: In function ‘rpl_fseeko’:
| ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c:110:4: error: #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|   110 |   #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
|       |    ^~~~~
| make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: fseeko.o] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
| make[2]: *** [Makefile:1674: all] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:1572: all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build'
| make: *** [Makefile:1528: all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2647129)
ERROR: Task (/home/hannes/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.18.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

This is the last significant part from /home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2647129

Does someone knows how to solve it ?

Comment: What is the log at `/home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2647129`

Comment: @lescaudr This is the last significant part from /home/hannes/git/alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-28/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2647129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interoperability problem between GNU m4 1.4.18 and newer glibc header files.

It is fixed in GNU m4 1.4.19, available from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/ and the GNU mirrors.

Comment: But how to apply m4 1.4.19 ? I did: 
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.19.tar.gz &&
tar -xvzf m4-1.4.19.tar.gz &&
cd m4-1.4.19/ &&
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/m4 &&
make

But system still uses 1.4.18

Comment: The complete answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69279143/1079990

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I compiling in yocto.

Please Remove this line

```
#if defined _IO_ftrylockfile || __GNU_LIBRARY__ == 1 /* GNU libc, BeOS, Haiku, Linux libc5 */
```

and add this line in the file.

```
#if defined _IO_EOF_SEEN || __GNU_LIBRARY__ == 1 /* GNU libc, BeOS, Haiku, Linux libc5 */
```

Also updated stdio-impl.h with:

```
/* Glibc 2.28 made _IO_IN_BACKUP private.  For now, work around this
problem by defining it ourselves.  FIXME: Do not rely on glibc
internals.  */

#if !defined _IO_IN_BACKUP && defined _IO_EOF_SEEN
# define _IO_IN_BACKUP 0x100
#endif
```